# How to automatically simulate server responses from a browser plugin (Firefox/Chromium)

Tags: ajax, testing, browser, simulate

While I am testing a web application, for some requests that are computational intensive on the server side, I would like to simulate the server response directly from a browser add-on. I would like to be able to configure the URL and set-up a JSON response that will be returned by the browser without sending the request to the server.

Does any of you know a good tool for this purpose ?

*P.S. So far I am either changing the server code to simulate the response or changing the client code to return the response without triggering the request to server.*